# How to replace searchable column “store_id” to "website_id" into Sales/Orders admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order, order-grid

I want to filter the orders by website (rather than store ID)

I have tried to remove:

```
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
            'index'     => 'store_id',
            'type'      => 'store',
            'store_view'=> true,
            'display_deleted' => true,
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id',
            ));
```

And to replace it by:

```
    $this->addColumn('website_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Website'),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'width'     => '80px',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteOptionHash(true),
            'index'     => 'website_id',
        ));
```

(Which I copied from app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php)

The website combo box shows the right websites, but the row value is blank.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [BL Custom Grid](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids)? It allows a lot of customization of the columns in sales, catalog, and some other grid pages.

Here's a screenshot of my `sales > orders` page. Column Titles and widths are customizable.

[image]

Comment: Does this extension support a filter by website?

Comment: Not that I see on my admin area. The "store_id" value is used for my "Purchased From (Store)" column in position 2.  The three levels from top to bottom are `website` , `store`, `store view`

Comment: Since I can't select the website that doesn't interest me

Comment: In Magento a `website` is actually the top level container for a group of stores and their store views. If you have multiple `stores` and `domains` on your Magento setup, you can use the drop down in "purchased from (store)" to select a specific `store view` which would relate directly to a `domain` for that store.